# How to fuse 2 image and keep the same filename / overwrite the original

Tags: imagemagick

I have 3 png image: a red square with a transparent background (1.png), a map (PLAN.png) and a color gradient with a transparent background (LEGEND.png). I want to first put the red square atop the map and then put the color gradient atop of it, while keeping the original filename of the red square for multiple files in multiple folders

Here's what I came up with in the windows cmd:

```
cd [location of the folder]
magick convert ../PLAN.png 1.png -compose multiply -composite 1.png && magick composite ../LEGEND.png 1.png 1.png
```

The problem is that for each file, I need to manually change 1.png to for example 1 2 3.png . I had used this command:

```
magick mogrify -gravity center -draw "image Over 0,0 0,0 '../PLAN2.png'" *.png
```

While with it I don't have to manually manually change the 1.png,  it doesn't work with the map since it put it atop of the red square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick 7, do the following. Note, use magick, not magick convert.

```
magick PLAN.png 1.png -compose over -composite LEGEND.png -compose over -composite 1.png
```

or

```
magick PLAN.png 1.png LEGEND.png -background none -flatten 1.png
```

Do either of those do what you want?